# How can I run local-exec provisionner AFTER cloud-init / user_data?

Tags: ansible, terraform

I'm experiencing a race condition issue on Terraform when running an Ansible playbook with the `local-exec` provisioner. At one point, that playbook has to install an APT package.

But first, I'm running a cloud-config file `init.yml` specified in the `user_data` argument that installs a package as well.
Consequently, I'm getting the following error :

```
Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

How can I prevent this?

---

```
# init.yml

runcmd:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get -y install python python3
```

---

```
# main.tf

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "hotdog" {
  image     = "ubuntu-18-04-x64"
  name      = "my_droplet"
  region    = "FRA1"
  size      = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
  user_data = file("init.yml")

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook -i '${self.ipv4_address},' ./playbook.yml"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: my terraform knowledge is quite sparse compared to my ansible one. The below should work but there might be terraform centric options I totally missed*

---

A very easy solution is to use an [`until` loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) so as to retry the task until it succeeds.

```yaml
- name: retry apt task every 5s during 1mn until it succeeds (e.g. lock is released)
  apt:
    name: my_package
  register: apt_install
  until: apt_install is success
  delay: 5
  retries: 12
```

A better approach would be to make sure there is no lock in place on the different dpkg lock files. I did not make the exercise to implement this in ansible and you might need a specific script or custom module to succeed. If you want to give it a try, there is [a question with a solution on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/221871/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-apt-lock-file-is-locked)

In your context and since this problem seems quite common actually, I searched a bit and I came across [this issue on github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/4668). I think that my adaptation as below will meet your requirements and might help for any other possible race condition inside your init phase.

Modify your `user_data` as:

```yaml
---
runcmd:
  - touch /tmp/user-init-running
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get -y install python python3
  - rm /tmp/user-init-running
```

And in your playbook:

```
- name: wait for init phase to end. Error after 1mn
  wait_for:
    path: /tmp/user-init-running
    state: absent
    delay: 60

- name: install package
  apt:
    name: mypkg
    state: present
```

Comment: Yes, that's the temporary solution I went for. But clearly not the ideal for other use-cases.

Comment: I beleive my edit yill meet your requirement.

Comment: Alternatively a `null_resource` triggered from the resource instead of a `local-exec` provisioner would also fix this race condition. More ideally, you could chain TF's infra prov into Ansible's soft prov in a pipeline with inventory interfaced from TF to Ansible to also avoid this.